# getting userID from a given twitter url page - Twitter4j

Tags: java, url, twitter, long-integer, twitter4j

How do I get the user id number(long) from his url twitter page?

```
Long userId;
URL url = new URL("https://twitter.com/MarketWatch");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to get the `User` of given screen name. Extract screen name from URL by using string methods, and use `showUser(java.lang.String screenName)`. Then you'll be able to get the id of specified user:

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
// Initialize your Twitter
User user = twitter.showUser("MarketWatch");
long userId = user.getId(); // Long ID of user @MarketWatch
```

Read about `GET users/show` in Twitter API:

- https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show

Since retrieving user data requires authentication, you have to provide your access token as well. Read about how to initialize your Twitter authenticating with OAuth:

- http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html#oauth

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on the API called `getId()`

> long getId()
>
> Returns the id of the user

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html?twitter4j/User.html